# How can I integrate $\int 5\sqrt{5+4x-x^2} \, dx$ using substitution?

Tags: integration

I know it is easier if we go through the $\sqrt{x^2+9}$ but I do not know how to integrate if we use $u=5+4x-x^2$ ? Or can we not use substitution like that?

Comment: $5+4x-x^2=9-(x-2)^2$ suggests a trig substitution. But you should study [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: If $u=5+4x-x^2$ the what is $dx?$

Comment: Thomas, du=(4-2x)dx. But I would strongly recommend using the trig substitution Jyrki mentioned.

Comment: @AlejandroJimenezTellado: I think the point that Thomas is trying to make is that it is difficult, if not impossible, to write $4-2x$ in terms of $u$, meaning that this substitution seems unworkable.

Comment: @Joe ahh yes, sorry haha.

Comment: I see, thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is "complete the square".  $x^2+ 4x+ 5= x^2+ 4x+ 4+ 1= (x+ 2)^2+ 1$ so $5\int \sqrt{x^2+ 4x+ 5}dx= 5\int\sqrt{(x+ 2)^2+ 1}dx$.

Let u= x+ 2 so du= dx and the integral becomes $5\int \sqrt{u^2+ 1}du$.

Now use a trig or hyperbolic substitution.

Comment: The coefficient of $x^2$ is $-1$, not $1$.

Comment: @Oussema, if I'm good at spotting errors, it's mainly because my own work has given me so much opportunity to practice.